# Okta single-sign-on keeps the previous user on new login

Tags: node.js, single-sign-on, logout, okta

I´m currently working on a SSO aplication implementing Okta SSO service but whenever a user logs out from the app and another user tries to log in, the login button automatically takes the previous user and logs in as that account without even going through the okta login page.

**Here's the deal:**

- User 1 login going through the okta login
- User 1 logout
- User 2 tries to login in the same computer
- Page automatically logsin as user 1

To really logout from that user I have to go to the app page in okta and logout the user directly from there and then and only then the login goes through the okta login page once again, i believe  I´m missing something in the log out code, i tried to destroy the user session with req.session.destoy but it didnt work and i dont know what else could it be.

Here's the logout code:

```
app.get('/logout', (req, res) => {
  req.logout();
  req.session.destroy();
  res.redirect('/');
});
```

Hope you all can help me out

Answer (score 1):

This is really SSO in action. Presumably this is on a shared device ?

For step 1, you are logging the user out of the application locally ? If so, User 1 *still* has a Okta session and therefore when User 2 tries to login on the same device, the Okta session is still valid. The user goes through the SSO process and ends up logged in as User 1.

SSO on shared devices needs some consideration. You can look at Single Logout, which uses loose standards to log the user out of the application locally, and Okta. Or you'll need to look at the appropriate Okta API to log a user out directly at the point you log the user out of the application locally. That will kill both sessions, and then User 2 will be prompted to authenticate.